# pgf: "Dimension too large" in a function which fits into a graph, /pgf/fpu=true does not help

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I want to plot a lognormal function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lognormal}{2}{%
%  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
  \pgfmathparse{1/(x*#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((ln(x)-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
%  \pgfmathresult
%  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10 ]
  \addplot {lognormal(ln(5),0.02)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces "Dimension too large" even that the function has moderate values. I guess that the problem lies in intermediate values within `exp()`. I tried `/pgf/fpu=true` (commented out in the source) as suggested [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36189/227733) but it did not help and even additionally confused PGF. The latter can be verified by replacing `lognormal(ln(5),0.02)` with `lognormal(ln(5),1)`.

How to draw the lognormal function in pgf? I tried to replace the problematic parts of the domain with *y ~ 0*:

```
\pgfmathparse{1/(x*#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(ifthenelse((ln(x)-#1)/sqrt(#2) < -10, -100, -((ln(x)-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2)))}
```

As seen, I do not use a square in the condition in order to avoid an overflow. However, for certain parameters, processing a single chart with that equation takes several seconds, and of the whole Tex document, with many charts, more than a minute. Is there a faster, more precise and more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit2:

The small wrapper made its way to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath-xfp). So the below code with an up to date LaTeX distribution is now just:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}

\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{lognormal}{3}
  {exp(-((ln(#1) - #2)^2) / (2 * (#3)^2)) / (#1 * #3 * sqrt(2 * pi))}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
  \addplot {lognormal(x,ln(5),0.02)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit:

I've created a small wrapper to define `pgfmath`-functions using `l3fp` [first posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597578/117050). With it the MWE here boils down to the following (the things between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` is the wrapper):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_pgffpeval_function_definition_tl
\int_new:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pgffpeval_declare_function:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \__pgffpeval_initialize_body:
    \int_step_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
          {
            \exp_not:n { \pgfmathsetmacro } \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_arg##1 }
              { \exp_not:n {####} ##1 }
          }
      }
    \__pgffpeval_define_function:nnnn {#2} {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pgffpeval_declare_function_processed_args:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \__pgffpeval_initialize_body:
    \int_zero:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#3}
      {
        \int_incr:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
          {
            \exp_not:n { \pgfmathsetmacro }
              \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_arg \int_use:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int }
              { \exp_not:n {##1} }
          }
      }
    \exp_args:NV
    \__pgffpeval_define_function:nnnn \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int {#1} {#2} {#4}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pgffpeval_initialize_body:
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
      {
        \group_begin:
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output~format=sci}%
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__pgffpeval_process_function_aux:n #1 { \exp_not:n {## #1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pgffpeval_process_function:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \exp_last_unbraced:Nx
    \cs_set_protected:cpn
      {
        { __pgffpeval_function_ #2 _cmd }
        \int_step_function:nN {#1} \__pgffpeval_process_function_aux:n
      }
      { \group_end: \exp_args:Nf \pgfmathparse { \fp_eval:n {#3} } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pgffpeval_define_function:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \__pgffpeval_process_function:nnn {#1} {#2} {#4}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
      {
        \use:x
          { 
            \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_function_ #2 _cmd }
            \int_step_function:nN {#1} \__pgffpeval_define_function_aux:n
          }
      }
    \exp_args:Nnno
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction {#2} {#3} \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__pgffpeval_define_function_aux:n #1
  { { \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_arg#1 } } }
\NewDocumentCommand \pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction { m m o m }
  {
    \IfValueTF {#3}
      { \pgffpeval_declare_function_processed_args:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
      { \pgffpeval_declare_function:nnn {#1} {#2} }
      {#4}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{lognormal}{3}
  {exp(-((ln(#1) - #2)^2) / (2 * (#3)^2)) / (#1 * #3 * sqrt(2 * pi))}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
  \addplot {lognormal(x,ln(5),0.02)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output and explanation like below.

---

The following uses `xfp` for the actual calculation, and `\pgfmathsetmacro` with the options `/pgf/fpu=true` and `/pgf/fpu/output format=sci` applied locally to ensure the input number format is understandable for `xfp` (as `pgfmath` uses a custom internal number representation when the FPU is used, which isn't understood by `xfp`).

The `\romannumeral` is used to ensure that `\fpeval` is fully done when the group is closed and therefore `\argA`, `\argB`, and `\argC` don't have the correct meaning anymore. The result is then again parsed by `\pgfmathparse` to make sure that `\pgfmathresult` holds the correct format for `pgf` outside of the function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[]{xfp}

\begin{document}    
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lognormal}{3}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=sci}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\argA{#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\argB{#2}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\argC{#3}%
    \expandafter
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\pgfmathparse\expandafter
    {%
      \romannumeral`\^^@%
      \fpeval{exp(-((ln(\argA)-\argB)^2)/(2*\argC^2))/(\argA*\argC*sqrt(2*pi))}%
    }%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
  \addplot {lognormal(x,ln(5),0.02)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it fast? No. Does it work? Yes:

[image]

Comment: It is not fast for `lognormal(x,ln(5),0.02)` but it is fast for `lognormal(x,ln(5),0.2)`, as if larger values made the computation slower. If fpu is used, where is exactly the bottleneck?

Comment: @scriptfoo I have no idea, as I don't know much about the internals of both, `pgfmath`'s FPU and `l3fp`.

Comment: @scriptfoo I did some benchmarking and `l3fp` (the thing behind `xfp`) is only marginally affected by the bigger value. An entire sweep with 100 values from `0.01` to `10` takes about 2.6% more time in the calculation for the smaller value, whereas a single assignment using `\pgfmathsetmacro\tmp{<num>}` takes 13.6% more time for the smaller value. So the choke is `pgfmath`'s number parsing.