# expl3 cannot see declared functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, expl3, pgfmath

> **This question led to a new package:**
> [`pgfmath-xfp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath-xfp)

I use `tikzpicture` with `expl3` if floating-point computations exceed the TeX range. The problem is, `expl3` cannot see declared functions, as illustrated in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        declare function={
            functionA(\x) = \fpeval{\x};
            functionB(\x) = \fpeval{ln(2)*functionA(\x)};
        },
    ]
    \draw [domain=0:1, variable=\x]
      plot ({\x}, {functionB(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Unknown fp word functionA.
l.20       plot ({\x}, {functionB(\x)})
```

Is it possible to make `expl3` see declared functions?

Comment: No, this is not possible. However you can try another approach, using `\pgfmathsetmacro` to evaluate `functionA(\x)` first and passing the result of that to `\fpeval`. Take a look at the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585016/117050) where I use `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### EDIT:

The wrapper first described below made its way to [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath-xfp), so the code with a recent LaTeX distribution is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}

\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{functionA}{1}{#1}
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{functionB}{1}[functionA(#1)]{ln(2) * #1}
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{fplog}{1}{ln(#1)}
% slow (but for demonstration)
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{nlogn}{1}[#1,fplog(#1)]{#1 * #2}
% faster variant of the above
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{NlogN}{1}{#1 * ln(#1)}
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{lognormal}{3}
  {exp(-((ln(#1) - #2)^2) / (2 * (#3)^2)) / (#1 * #3 * sqrt(2 * pi))}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [domain=0:1, variable=\x]
    plot ({\x}, {functionB(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
    \addplot {lognormal(x,ln(5),0.2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
    \addplot {nlogn(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
    \addplot {NlogN(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output like below.

---

I've created a wrapper to define `pgfmath` functions which use `\fpeval` internally. The syntax is the following:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{<name>}{<arg-count>}[<arg-processors>]{<function>}
```

In this

- `<name>` is the name of the function
- `<arg-count>` is the number of arguments the `pgfmath`-function will take
- `<arg-processors>` is an optional comma-separated list of processed arguments. Those processed arguments will be processed by `pgfmath` (so here you could use nested functions).
- `<function>` is the function how it should be parsed by `\fpeval`. The number of arguments inside of `<function>` is the number of arguments declared in the `<arg-processors>` list if it was used, else it is equal to the number provided as `<arg-count>`

Note that the functions defined this way aren't exactly fast, but should work in every `pgfmath` context.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_pgffpeval_function_definition_tl
\int_new:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pgffpeval_declare_function:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \__pgffpeval_initialize_body:
    \int_step_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
          {
            \exp_not:n { \pgfmathsetmacro } \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_arg##1 }
              { \exp_not:n {####} ##1 }
          }
      }
    \__pgffpeval_define_function:nnnn {#2} {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pgffpeval_declare_function_processed_args:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \__pgffpeval_initialize_body:
    \int_zero:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#3}
      {
        \int_incr:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
          {
            \exp_not:n { \pgfmathsetmacro }
              \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_arg \int_use:N \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int }
              { \exp_not:n {##1} }
          }
      }
    \exp_args:NV
    \__pgffpeval_define_function:nnnn \l_pgffpeval_tmp_int {#1} {#2} {#4}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pgffpeval_initialize_body:
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
      {
        \group_begin:
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output~format=sci}%
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__pgffpeval_process_function_aux:n #1 { \exp_not:n {## #1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pgffpeval_process_function:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \exp_last_unbraced:Nx
    \cs_set_protected:cpn
      {
        { __pgffpeval_function_ #2 _cmd }
        \int_step_function:nN {#1} \__pgffpeval_process_function_aux:n
      }
      { \group_end: \exp_args:Nf \pgfmathparse { \fp_eval:n {#3} } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pgffpeval_define_function:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \__pgffpeval_process_function:nnn {#1} {#2} {#4}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
      {
        \use:x
          { 
            \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_function_ #2 _cmd }
            \int_step_function:nN {#1} \__pgffpeval_define_function_aux:n
          }
      }
    \exp_args:Nnno
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction {#2} {#3} \l_pgffpeval_function_body_tl
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__pgffpeval_define_function_aux:n #1
  { { \exp_not:c { __pgffpeval_arg#1 } } }
\NewDocumentCommand \pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction { m m o m }
  {
    \IfValueTF {#3}
      { \pgffpeval_declare_function_processed_args:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
      { \pgffpeval_declare_function:nnn {#1} {#2} }
      {#4}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{functionA}{1}{#1}
\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{functionB}{1}[functionA(#1)]{ln(2) * #1}
\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{fplog}{1}{ln(#1)}
% slow (but for demonstration)
\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{nlogn}{1}[#1,fplog(#1)]{#1 * #2}
% faster variant of the above
\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{NlogN}{1}{#1 * ln(#1)}
\pgfmathdeclarefpevalfunction{lognormal}{3}
  {exp(-((ln(#1) - #2)^2) / (2 * (#3)^2)) / (#1 * #3 * sqrt(2 * pi))}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [domain=0:1, variable=\x]
    plot ({\x}, {functionB(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
    \addplot {lognormal(x,ln(5),0.2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
    \addplot {nlogn(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ domain=0.01:10, samples=100 ]
    \addplot {NlogN(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]